# How to deploy pubsub-triggered cloud function with message ordering?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I want to deploy a Pubsub-triggered Cloud Function with message ordering:
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/ordering

`gcloud functions deploy` doesn't have an option to set an `--enable-message-ordering` option:
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy

Should I pre-create the subscription before deploying the function? If so, does Cloud Functions have a well-known format for how it matches to a subscription name? It seems maybe the format is: `gcf-{function-name}-{region}-{topic-name}`, but it also looks like the name format has changed over time, e.g. older deployed functions don't have the region name in the subscription. Is there a stable way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must create message ordering pub/sub and Cloud function manually.

Fisrt, Create a pub/sub topic, and then create a subscription that subscribes pub/sub topic with  `--enable-message-ordering`

Second, Create a Cloud function that will serve ordered pub/sub messages.

Last, back to the pub/sub subscription, Edit delivery type to push and specify your cloud function endpoint.

[image]

So final diagram is like below.

Publisher -> Pub/sub topic -> Pub/sub subscriber -> Cloud function

You tried to make a connection Pub/sub topic with Cloud function directly.

But for message ordering, Pub/sub needs topic -> subscriber connection.

So only pub/sub topic -> pub/sub subscriber -> Cloud function connection can delivers ordered messages to your function.

Comment: The approach you suggest would use an http triggered function, whereas I'd prefer to have it natively pubsub-triggered. That way, I don't have to worry about authentication configuration, and the function can directly accept the message data rather than implement an express request handler. As a side point, there is always a pubsub subscriber. It's just that the pubsub-triggered function setup deals with creating the subscription automatically.

Comment: Sadly, there is no native pubsub-triggered way with message ordering. You should choose between http-triggerd way with order and pubsub-triggerd way with unorder. Because pubsub triggered Cloud function will be triggered bia pubsub topic only.But message ordering need pubsub topic and pubsub subscribe connection.

Comment: Do you work for Google? What is your basis for claiming there is no way. For example why can’t I pre-define the subscription using the well defined subscription name used by the function and then deploy the function?

Comment: As you can see,The push subscription created automaically(gcf-{function-name}-{region}-{topic-name}) has an URL endpoint with `appspot.com`.This is for Cloud function's pubsub triggering. You can't reuse this subscription as It uses an Appengine implicitly. When you delete this pubsub subscription to re-create with message ordering, You can't designate this URL endpoint again. In summary, You can't re-use automatically created pubsub subscription, and you don't need to do so to achieve your purpose

Answer (score 0):

When declaring a Pub/Sub **topic** with a Cloud Function alike:

```
exports.pubsub = functions.pubsub.topic('some-topic').onPublish((message, context) => {}
```

The problem is that message ordering is only available for the subscription, but not for the topic.
On deploy a push subscription is automatically being created at: [`cloudpubsub/subscription/list`](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudpubsub/subscription/list) (the one which starts with `gcf-*`). This only appears to work when manually subscribing to a topic: [Enabling message ordering](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/ordering). I haven't yet tried if it would pick up a subscription with the same name; if everything fails, one still could record the messages and then order by timestamp or a "sequence token": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQ9_Xur2aM4.