# How can I enable Order message with Ordering Key in GCP Cloud Pub/Sub Triggered Function Gen 2?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm deploying my Cloud Pub/Sub Triggered Event Function and here is my command:

```
- gcloud
- beta
- functions
- deploy
- 'pubsub_triggered_function'
- '--gen2'
- '--runtime=dotnet6'
- '--region=europe-west3'
- '--source=${_GIT_REPO}'
- '--entry-point=entrypint_name_example'
- '--trigger-topic=topic-A'
```

The above command will deploy the function and listen to the `google.cloud.pubsub.topic.v1.messagePublished event` of the `topic-A`, and it also automatically create `1 Eventarc Trigger` and `1 Subscription (calls it Subscription A)` to `topic-A` to achieve that. As I understand, the actual resource triggers the function is the auto-added `subscription A`. Now I want to edit this subscription to enable `Order message with Ordering key` but the GCP Console prevents that.

[image]

Is there anyway to edit this property of the auto-added subscription? I've tried to delete this subscription and create it manually but it wouldn't be able to trigger the `Eventarc trigger` to fire the function.

Answer (score 1):

The answer could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65692307/how-to-deploy-pubsub-triggered-cloud-function-with-message-ordering?rq=2) in the comment section. It turns out that when I deploy the function by using the flag `--trigger-topic=topic-A`, the function will be triggered by the `pub/sub trigger` which is powered by the `Eventarc`, and this type of trigger doesn't support `order message`. Therefore, `Eventarc trigger` is not a suitable solution in this case, then I find out that we can directly push the message to the cloud function from `Pub/Sub Subscription`, and it does support sending messages by order key.

Comment: Correct answer! It's not possible with the built in feature of Cloud Functions. You have to create an HTTP function and to plug a PubSub subscription, with all the feature you wish, on it (it's the same for the filtering feature for instance!)